# How to keep an historical of all changes in a database? SQL Server / MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What model / architecture should we follow in order to implement a historical database, with all changes to each record in an operational database, so as to be able to reconstruct all information from the time of "creation of the record" in time? "Any changes" and possibly the "removal", knowing which authenticated user is responsible for the action?

Comment: SQL Server already offers some mechanisms of its own for this, depending on version and edition: [change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server), [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) and [auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine). None are an exact match for a fully historical database, but they're still worth looking into.

Comment: The CDC feature @JeroenMostert mentioned requires Enterprise Edition prior to SQL 2016 SP1 but is available in Standard after that. It's a good idea to add a version-specific tag to your question unless you are unconstrained.

Comment: This seems to be what a regular backup does? That is a full db backup and then let the db store transaction files. So a restore would be restore the full backup and apply the transaction files in order up until the last statement.

Comment: @NikolajHansen: that gives you no information on what users changed what data, nor is it by any means quick or easy to determine the history of individual records this way. Point in time restores are not the same thing as a transaction history. They can be used as a troubleshooting aid, but if you know you need full history in advance, it's worth setting up something a little more accessible.